# Intellij Idea - how to get rid of thick caret/cursor

Tags: intellij-idea, caret

I pressed something in Intellij and my caret shape changed to this. How to revert to the normal thickness? Using Intellij 2016.1.

[image: thick caret]

Compare to this, normal thickness should be that of a bold vertical line:

[image: normal caret]

Update: On Android Studio 2.1 beta, same machine, same font settings, cursor is visibly thinner.

Comment: *"Update: On Android Studio 2.1 beta, same machine, same font settings, cursor is visibly thinner."* Just a thought -- they may use different Java versions... or be different builds (compare `Help | About` screens)

Comment: Found **ThinCaret plugin** -- seems to do exactly that.

Answer (score 12):

You can .. but it's not pixel perfect. I mean -- for me the value does not seem to control thickness in pixels but rather some index (which gets applied to some predefined values) -- *at least this is my impression* on what I see my computer.

In any case:

1. `Help | Find Action...`
2. Search for `registry` action
3. Once in Registry window -- look for `editor.caret.width` entry
4. Set the new value (for me the default was `2`) -- make sure that field went bold (move to another entry) to ensure that new value was accepted.
5. Restart IDE (this option requires it)

---

**UPDATE (2017/04/06):**

You may also try **ThinCaret plugin**:

> Makes your editor caret 1 pixel thin (for retina users)

Comment: Tried that. Only integer values are accepted. Val. 1 is too thin, like in Notepad++. Value 3 is even thicker. Looks like for val=1 it is half the regular value, but for val.2 it is twice the regular. If I could put 1.5 ...

Comment: Well -- you asked "how" -- I told you how and warned that it's not perfect (unfortunately). Right now I may suggest to try different fonts (they can be related -- try `Consolas` for example). Maybe you are using font scaling (at OS level) or HiDPI screen? My PhpStorm 2016.1.1 on Windows 7 seems to have good caret size by default.

Comment: excellent answer, thanks! I have a very large 4K monitor and I struggled to find the caret sometimes, but I also don't like the block-caret. Simply setting it from width 2 to 4 makes a huge difference.

Comment: @Hans You may also try [ThinCaret plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8044-thincaret) -- maybe it works better (no idea what exactly it does though -- I have standard monitor).

Answer (score 7):

You can change it under `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Use Block caret`

Other caret settings are under `Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General`. Then if you scroll down to the editor section on the right, there is a `caret` item in the list with font/color settings.

Comment: This is not related to block caret. As you can see, caret is thinner than the "block caret" mode, but thicker than the regular caret.

Answer (score 5):

Please check the Picture for solution.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you got here because of the thick cursor (block cursor) that behaves differently than the normal thin one. Just press the insert (Ins) button once and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Just create your own shortcut to toggle between Insert and Overwrite mode]
Go to the Keymaps section of the Preferences and add your own Keyboard shortcut if you are using a Mac. Windows users can just enable/disable Insert mode on their keyboard.

Comment: Yo, that was very helpful mate, thank you. Pls can you explain why even that thick very annoying caret does exist? What's its purpose. Thx again!

Comment: Yeah I must have mistakenly tapped the `insert` key. Tapping again returned the cursor/caret back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the block caret in CLion by JetBrains, click the "Insert" key on your keyboard. This will toggle the block caret on and off. Do not wrap your head around trying to understand how the block caret works. This also works for all JetBrains IDEs such as Clion, PyCharm, Fleet, etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).